# Javascript: JSON.parse() prevent auto type conversion

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to leave numbers as strings while using `JSON.parse();`, but JavaScript does auto type conversion. My number string which is `"12345.6890"` converts to a number, which would be ok, if the `0` did not get truncated. I was trying to use a reviver function, but in the function

```
JSON.parse('12345.67890', (key, value) => { ... });
```

`typeof value` is already a number, also truncated. Can anyone think of an easy work around to treat everything as a string, or is the only solution to write my own Json parser?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `JSON.parse('"12345.67890"', (key, value) => { ... });` instead.

JSON expects strings to be wrapped in double quotes

```js
console.log(typeof(JSON.parse('12345.678')));
console.log(typeof(JSON.parse('"12345.678"')));
```

Comment: To clarify... not just the JavaScript JSON object requires double quotes, the JSON spec itself specifies double quotes. (see http://json.org)